# InStr - only look in the first part of the string

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dataset that contains a few thousand rows and I am searching each row for specific text within the strings: 7-16, 7-26, 7-36, 13414, SHIPP, CONTAI...etc. (more of them shown below).

The problem is that sometimes some part numbers have the "# - ##" at the end of the part and not at the beginning and so the macro is also classifying it as "Container / PGSE Part/Trainers" when it really is not.

So I am looking for syntax that will only look at the first 4 characters of a string in the cell (only for the ones that contain the part numbers, not words).

For example:

If it were to look at a cell containing "**7-26**734372-102" I *would* want it to classify it as a "Container / PGSE Part/Trainers" in column 51

If it were to look at a cell containing "MS3520**7-26**3" I *would not* want it to classify it as a "Container / PGSE Part/Trainers" in column 51 because it is in the end of the string.

```
Sub PGSE_Container_Trainer()

Dim rw As Integer

Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

rw = 2

Do Until sht.Cells(rw, 1) = ""

If InStr(1, Cells(rw, 8).Value, "7-16") Then
    sht.Cells(rw, 51) = "Container / PGSE Part/Trainers"
    GoTo LoopSkip
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(rw, 8).Value, "7-26") Then
    sht.Cells(rw, 51) = "Container / PGSE Part/Trainers"
    GoTo LoopSkip
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(rw, 8).Value, "7-36") Then
    sht.Cells(rw, 51) = "Container / PGSE Part/Trainers"
    GoTo LoopSkip
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(rw, 8).Value, "7-46") Then
    sht.Cells(rw, 51) = "Container / PGSE Part/Trainers"
    GoTo LoopSkip
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(rw, 8).Value, "7-56") Then
    sht.Cells(rw, 51) = "Container / PGSE Part/Trainers"
    GoTo LoopSkip
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(rw, 8).Value, "7-66") Then
    sht.Cells(rw, 51) = "Container / PGSE Part/Trainers"
    GoTo LoopSkip
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(rw, 8).Value, "7-76") Then
    sht.Cells(rw, 51) = "Container / PGSE Part/Trainers"
    GoTo LoopSkip
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(rw, 8).Value, "7-86") Then
    sht.Cells(rw, 51) = "Container / PGSE Part/Trainers"
    GoTo LoopSkip
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(rw, 8).Value, "7-96") Then
    sht.Cells(rw, 51) = "Container / PGSE Part/Trainers"
    GoTo LoopSkip
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(rw, 8).Value, "13414") Then
    sht.Cells(rw, 51) = "Container / PGSE Part/Trainers"
    GoTo LoopSkip
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(rw, 9).Value, "CONTAI") Then
    sht.Cells(rw, 51) = "Container / PGSE Part/Trainers"
    GoTo LoopSkip
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(rw, 9).Value, "CNTNR") Then
    sht.Cells(rw, 51) = "Container / PGSE Part/Trainers"
    GoTo LoopSkip
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(rw, 9).Value, "SHIPP") Then
    sht.Cells(rw, 51) = "Container / PGSE Part/Trainers"
    GoTo LoopSkip
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(rw, 8).Value, "REN") Then
    sht.Cells(rw, 51) = "Container / PGSE Part/Trainers"
    GoTo LoopSkip
End If

LoopSkip:
rw = rw + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Use the Left function.

Comment: Use condition `If InStr(1, Cells(rw, 8).Value, "7-16") = 1 Then`. This will check if `7-16` is at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a slightly different approach: replace you multiple `If`s and `ElseIf`s with `Select Case`.

Replace your `Instr` with `Like` and add the wild-card `*` at the end to look for the first 4 letters. e.g `Cells(rw, 8).Value Like "7-16*"`.

There is a nice "trick" to use `Select Case`, with `Like` and the wild-card `*`, see in my code below.

**Note**: try to avoid using `ActiveSheet` and instead use fully qualifed objects, like `Set Sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub PGSE_Container_Trainer()

Dim rw As Long
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim CVal As Variant

Set Sht = Worksheets("Sheet1") ' it's better to avoid using ActiveSheet

rw = 2
With Sht
    Do Until .Cells(rw, 1) = ""
        CVal = .Cells(rw, 8).Value
        Select Case True '<-- the trick to have the `Like` inside the Case
            Case CVal Like "7-16*", CVal Like "7-26*", CVal Like "7-36*", CVal Like "7-46*", CVal Like "7-56*", _
                    CVal Like "7-66*", CVal Like "7-76*", CVal Like "7-86*", CVal Like "7-96*", CVal Like "13414*"
                .Cells(rw, 51) = "Container / PGSE Part/Trainers"

        End Select

        ' add more select cases to fit your needs here...

        rw = rw + 1
    Loop
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the format is always "#-##' then do something like:
`If Instr(1, String, "-") = 2 then`

Since Instr returns the position index, you can classify it by the number.

You may also be able to do something like:
 `if String like "#-########-##" then`

The like operator will check if a string satisfies a pattern, so you should be able to use this to explicitly define a pattern, and see if the string satisfies the given pattern. For more information, check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251796.aspx

Also, if you wanted to explicitly match the first three characters to a substring you could do something like:

`If Left(String, 3) = SubString then`

For example:

```
Dim SearchString as String: SearchString = "1-2-3_IsThisThingOn"
Dim SubString as String: SubString = "1-2-3"

' Returns "1-2-3"
Debug.Print Left(SearchString, 5)

' Returns true
Debug.Print Left(SearchString, 5) = "1-2-3"

SubString = "4-5-6"

'Returns false
Debug.Print Left(SearchString, 5) = "1-2-3"
```